# uma_zalloc and uma_zfree are thread safe in freebsd kernel space?

Tags: memory, kernel, freebsd, space, pool

I have two threads which in both of them I use uma_zalloc() and uma_zfree() functions for the one variable of uma_zone_t.
I want to know uma_zone_t is thread safe or not?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the use of the zone pointer is thread safe with respect to concurrent allocations and frees.  The zone structure manages a pool of memory and the UMA interfaces do not require external synchronization.